# LINQ To SQL Join with IEnumerable<Non-Premitive Type>

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-entities

I have a list of items say:

```
public class Data
{
    public Id int;
    public Name string;
}

IEnumerable<Data> data = new List<Data>() { new Data(){Id = 1, Name = "1"}, new Data(){Id = 2, Name = "2"}};
```

Now I want to fetch data from SQL db using linq

```
var result = (from a in dbContext.Table1
             join b in dbContext.Table2 on Table1.Key equals Table2.Key
             join d in data on new { a.Id, b.Name } equals new { d.Id, d.Name}
             select a).ToList();
```

Above this is not working w/ exception that only Premetive Types or IEnumerable are allowed.

How can I achieve this thing?

Comment: bare in mind that this approach will have to query all data to the client and then join with IEnumerable; it may be better to supply filter to dbContext to run filtering on SQL server side.

Comment: Please tag the correct data library. This is *not* LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: @GertArnold Done. Which LINQ library will it be?

Comment: @Michael That's the problem here I have a list of pair of value based on which I want filtering. Me too want it to happen on SQL side.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check equality by id and by name separately:

```
a.Id == b.Id && a.Name == b.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
var result = (from a in dbContext.Table1
             join b in dbContext.Table2 on Table1.Key equals Table2.Key
             join d in data on a.Id equals d.Id
             where b.Name == d.Name
             select a).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem is in `join d in data`. There's no SQL translation of `data`.

Comment: Is Id in database a string or a number?  You c# code is using an integer.

Comment: @jdweng What about if the no of columns increases in my data?

Comment: The output is the entire table 'a' from the code "select a".